# Windsor castle policy injection tutorial?

Tags: castle-windsor

I would like to learn more about Windsor castle but it seems that it is overwhelming me a bit. I found a code sample here: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/03/07/Building-the-Policy-Injection-in-40-Minutes-with-Windsor.aspx. It's interesting indeed but it seems to be using a lot of extra code. I thought the power for policy injection was just that I could make some configuration file and inject it and have a pre-, post, and interception handler?

Comment: I think the question is clear: I simply am looking for a decent tutorial that explains Windsor Castle policy injection which makes use of a simple interceptor class/handler and only uses configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you misunderstood Ayende's post. Windsor is **not** the same thing as policy injection application block from Patterns and Practices. This functionality *could* be implemented in Windsor, as Ayende showed, but that would be far from the main goal of the project.

If you want just simple AOP, check Castle Dynamic Proxy.

If you want to learn more about Windsor, there are plenty of good resources out there.

Some links:

[probably the most complete Dynamic Proxy tutorial by yours truly](http://kozmic.pl/archive/2009/04/27/castle-dynamic-proxy-tutorial.aspx)

[IMO best Windsor tutorial](http://wiki.bittercoder.com/Default.aspx?Page=ContainerTutorials&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

[Another Windsor tutorial](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/designpatterns/inversionofcontrolanddependencyinjectionwithcastlewindsorcontainerpart1.aspx)

[You may also want to see Steve Bohlen's recording from NotAtPDC about it (not available yet, but should be soon)](http://www.notatpdc.com/)

[And Ayende's very good introductory presentation from NDC conference.](http://media01.smartcom.no/microsite/asx.aspx?eventid=4534)

Comment: I thought Windsor Castle was the policy injection part. I guess I was mistaking then. Can you please update your reply with some good starter tutorials for beginners for both Castle Windsor (and for what it is meant) and that Castle Dynamic Proxy?